# using pybind11 to wrap yaml-cpp iterator

Tags: c++, pybind11, yaml-cpp

I am trying to wrap some of the yaml-cpp code with pybind11. I realize there is a python module for manipulating yaml files, but I would appreciate help with this approach. I am just trying to get familiar with pybind11.

Specifically, I would like to wrap the iterator for a `YAML::Node`, but the return type from the iterator is not a `YAML::Node`, it is a `YAML::detail::iterator_value`. How do I go from this type back to a `YAML::Node`in the iterator lambda function? Here are the relevant parts of my code.

utilities_py.cc

```
#include "yaml-cpp/yaml.h"
#include "pybind11/pybind11.h"

PYBIND11_MODULE(utilities, m) {
  namespace py = pybind11;

    py::class_<YAML::detail::iterator_value>(m, "YamlDetailIteratorValue")
        .def(py::init<>());

    py::class_<YAML::Node>(m, "YamlNode")
        .def(py::init<const std::string &>())
        .def("__getitem__",
            [](const YAML::Node node, const std::string key){
              return node[key];
            })
        .def("__iter__",
            [](const YAML::Node &node) {
              return py::make_iterator(node.begin(), node.end());},
             py::keep_alive<0, 1>());

    m.def("load_file", &YAML::LoadFile, "");
}
```

test_utilities_py.py

```
from utilities import load_file

test_node = load_file('test.yaml')
for nodelette in test_node:
    prop = nodelette['prop']
```

And I get the following error:

```
TypeError: __getitem__: incompatible function arguments. The following argument types are supported:
    1. (arg0: utilities.YamlNode, arg1: str) -> utilities.YamlNode

Invoked with: <utilities.YamlDetailIteratorValue object at 0x7f8babc446f0>, 'prop'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. If you look at the source, `YAML::detail::iterator_value` extends `YAML::Node`, so you have to account for that in the python code. It also extends `std::pair<YAML::Node, YAML::Node>`, so that will need to be accounted for in some way as well.

```
struct iterator_value : public Node, std::pair<Node, Node> {
```

When that gets bound, we'll have to make sure that Node is bound as the parent class. That will look like:

```
py::class_<YAML::detail::iterator_value, YAML::Node>(m, "YamlDetailIteratorValue")
```

Now you have all the Node methods when you iterate, which is good! But you're going to run into real trouble because of the fact that `iterator_value` also inherits from `std::pair`. As far as I know, there is no way to just use that as a parent type in pybind11, even though it has auto-conversions for pairs (there is `bind_vector` and `bind_map` but no `bind_pair`). I think you could write your own binding for such a thing, but I'm not sure it is necessary. Really what you need to do is inspect the type of the `Node` you are about to iterate over and then iterate a little differently  depending on if it is map or a sequence (this is similar to how the c++ api works where there is a single iterator type for both sequences and maps, but certain functions will fail if called in the wrong context).

Here is how I ended up solving the problem:

```
PYBIND11_MODULE(utilities, m) {
    py::enum_<YAML::NodeType::value>(m, "NodeType")
    .value("Undefined", YAML::NodeType::Undefined)
    .value("Null", YAML::NodeType::Null)
    .value("Scalar", YAML::NodeType::Scalar)
    .value("Sequence", YAML::NodeType::Sequence)
    .value("Map", YAML::NodeType::Map);

    py::class_<YAML::Node>(m, "YamlNode")
        .def(py::init<const std::string &>())
        .def("__getitem__",
            [](const YAML::Node node, const std::string& key){
              return node[key];
            })
        .def("__iter__",
            [](const YAML::Node &node) {
              return py::make_iterator(node.begin(), node.end());},
             py::keep_alive<0, 1>())
        .def("__str__",
             [](const YAML::Node& node) {
               YAML::Emitter out;
               out << node;
               return std::string(out.c_str());
             })
        .def("type", &YAML::Node::Type)
        .def("__len__", &YAML::Node::size)
        ;

    py::class_<YAML::detail::iterator_value, YAML::Node>(m, "YamlDetailIteratorValue")
        .def(py::init<>())
        .def("first", [](YAML::detail::iterator_value& val) { return val.first;})
        .def("second", [](YAML::detail::iterator_value& val) { return val.second;})
        ;

    m.def("load_file", &YAML::LoadFile, "");
```

I bound in the NodeType enum, so you can have that exposed when you call `type` on a node. Then I bound in `first` and `second` for the `iterator_value` type, so you can access the map values in a loop. you can switch on `type()` to figure out how to iterate. My example yaml file

```
---
 doe: "a deer, a female deer"
 ray: "a drop of golden sun"
 pi: 3.14159
 xmas: true
 french-hens: 3
 calling-birds:
   - huey
   - dewey
   - louie
   - fred
 xmas-fifth-day:
   calling-birds: four
   french-hens: 3
   golden-rings: 5
   partridges:
     count: 1
     location: "a pear tree"
   turtle-doves: two
```

And my example python (3.8) code using the bound c++

```
import example
from example import load_file

def iterator(node):
    if node.type() == example.NodeType.Sequence:
        return node
    elif node.type() == example.NodeType.Map:
        return ((e.first(), e.second()) for e in node)
    return (node,)

test_node = load_file('test.yml')


for key, value in iterator(test_node):
    if value.type() == example.NodeType.Sequence:
        print("list")
        for v in iterator(value):
            print(v)
    elif value.type() == example.NodeType.Map:
        print("map")
        for k,v in iterator(value):
            temp = value[str(k)]
            print(k, v)
            print(str(v) == str(temp))
```

Demonstrates correct iteration for the different types as well as the fact that `__get__` works on maps just as well as it does when calling `.second` on the `iterator_value`. You probably want to override `__get__` on ints, so it will let you do sequence access as well.

You've got a bonus `__str__` method as well, to make all the `print` calls work.